# Is it possible to implement bean pattern with a function that returns object of super class?

Tags: java, oop

Say I have two classes `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, which inherit from the abstract class `List`.
I have a method `InsertEnd` in `List` which inserts data to the end of the `List` and returns the `List`,implemented by the derived classes, to allow bean pattern.

Since `InsertEnd` is an inherited method, it has to return a `List`,so will writing statements like:

```
ArrayList arrlist = new ArrayList().InsertEnd(10).InsertEnd(15);
```

work because after the first call, we get a `List` and not `ArrayList`?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList().insertEnd(5).insertEnd(10);

}

abstract class List{
    public abstract List insertEnd(int data);
}

class ArrayList extends List{
    public List insertEnd(int data){
        //do insertion
        return this;
    }

}

class LinkedList extends List{
    public List insertEnd(int data){
        //do insertion
        return this;
    }
```

gives me a compile time error at `ArrayList arr = new  ArrayList().insertEnd(5).insertEnd(10);` for incompatible types.

Is there a workaround which allows me both bean pattern and having an abstract super class?
I am new to java, and apologize for not being familiar with conventions.

Comment: Hint: look into Java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase always. Beyond that please provide a real [mcve] please. I am not sure what your current input is supposed to really mean.

Comment: You can easily test it. Where did you fail?

Comment: And don't use raw types. The `ArrayList` class accepts a generic type as parameter.

Comment: Well, change the return type of ArrayList.insertEnd() to ArrayList. But that said, you should program to interfaces, and your variable should be of type List anyway.

Comment: @MCEmperor So you haven't noticed that OP uses his own classes?

Comment: @Tom How inconvenient.

Comment: @MCEmperor Indeed :D

Comment: @JBNizet Can you elaborate more please? I changed the return type to ArrayList, and the error went away. Is this because of down casting?

Comment: No, it's because now the method returns an ArrayList, and and the returned value can thus be assigned to a variable of type ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your sub classes aren't returning the proper type. Since the subclass is an instance of the superclass, you can return an instance of itself.

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList().insertEnd(5).insertEnd(10);
    }
}

abstract class List {
    public abstract List insertEnd(int data);
}

class ArrayList extends List {
    @Override
    public ArrayList insertEnd(int data) {
        // do insertion
        return this;
    }
}

class LinkedList extends List {
    @Override
    public LinkedList insertEnd(int data) {
        // do insertion
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `the subclass is an instance of the superclass, you can return an instance of itself.` clarified things for me!

Comment: The class names you are using (List, ArrayList and LinkedList) are in the java.util package. Your coding here is not in any way overriding their function and never can, so don't expect to have their functionality unless you code it yourself in your new classes.